# Marionette itemViewEvents; event dispatching and binding

Tags: marionette

I'm having some trouble understanding how event dispatching and binding to events between children parents work in the awesomeness that is Marionette.

Is it correct that I can trigger a custom event from an itemView like this:

```
var Item = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
      "click .foo": "do:something"
    }
});

var itemCollection = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: item,
    initialize: function () {
        this.on("itemview:do:something", this.onSomething, this);
    }
}};
```

Is there some shortcut to binding to the itemView events like I would DOM events:

```
 var itemCollection = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: item,
    itemviewevents: {
        "itemview:do:something": "onSomething"
    }
}};
```

Thanks :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confusing triggers and events. Your code should be

```
var Item = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    triggers: {
      "click .foo": "do:something"
    }
});
```

Use the `events` hash to have a function called when an event takes place, use the `triggers` hash to have a trigger executed.

Comment: But is there any reason it would be a bad idea if it was possible to listen for the events with a configuration hash? ie. itemviewEvents: {...} ?

Comment: You should update your initial post to remove your "update", as it may confuse users unfamiliar with Marionette and triggers if they don't scroll down to the answer.

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to the OP's question? If not, I'm not sure I understand how you think I should change my answer.

Comment: Remove the update thing. by request of Tyler Harden.